# Error When Connect to sys from toad or PL/SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle10g, toad, sys

When I try to connect to my 10g Oracle database as sys from toad(9.0.1.8) or SQL Tools, I am getting error

```
insufficient privileges
```

I could connect to sys from sqlplus though.

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: you solve this by logging in as a higher priviledged user.

Comment: I am trying to connect as sys or system as sysdba. So I guess that's the highest privileged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a remote login password file.  See [this](http://fshaikh.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/enable-remote-sysdba-login/) page.